# Is there any method or methodology at OpenCV for movement understanding?

Tags: python

Is there any method or methodology at OpenCV for movement understanding ? or keywords ? I didn't ask about motion or movement detection .I hope ı explained well.If ı have to give an example ,  movement input : grabbing, movement input : walking.It has to be tag them like that. Thank you.

Comment: It always helps to add an example @Hamdi KAPTAN

Comment: Do you mean classify movements by image recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're referring to action recognition.  Here's one resource: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d8b/group__datasets__ar.html